# Mapnik Tilecache Settings

Tags: postgis, mapnik, tilecache

I installed mapnik and created XML files for creating map. Using a python I created the image corresponding to the XML File point to a postgis enabled postgresql database. Then I downloaded the tilecache and configured the .cfg file as follows,

```
[Outer]
type=Mapnik
mapfile=/var/www/html/mf/outer.xml
bbox=291627,904686,958569,1426831
srs=EPSG:32643
debug=no

[cache]
type=Disk 
base=/var/www/html/cachedata
```

I configured in apache 000-default.conf file as,

```
<Directory /var/www/html/tilecache>
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
   Options +ExecCGI

</Directory>
```

Then I run the url.

http://localhost/tilecache/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/Outer/0/0/0.png

got 404 Page not found error

http://localhost/tilecache/tilecache.cgi shows the text code itself.

No tiles creating and  given the cache folder full permission.  Please help.

Comment: Nobody answered... Nobody knows...